# Rendering Problems Android with Shape tag

Tags: android, drawable

I have spent a whole day trying to find the problem, and I have not found the solution. I need all your help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

And I call this way

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="New Button"
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:background="@drawable/shape_button" />
```

Error:

> Rendering Problems 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:598)
>     at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:120)
>     at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:236)
>     at
>   android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:783)
>     at android.view.View.(View.java:3554)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:623)   at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)   at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:103)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:756)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:728)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:728)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:728)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Drawable file, in Android Studio appear like and xml, and in the explorer not, just rename the files with the right extension. (*.xml)